# Printing only full DIVs on a page

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a page that has about 20 divs one under the other on it.
what i'd like to do is to print the page like this:

- 4 divs go fully on one printed page.
- the first half of 5th div gets printed on page 1 and the other half on page 2.
- this repeast for all 20 divs.
- i'd like to have first 4 divs on page
  one and the 2nd page to start with
  div 5 and so one.

so each printed page would contain only full divs.
also the div height is not known. so there can be 1 or 7 full divs per page.

EDIT:
I've tried all page-break-before and page-break-inside options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't do it exactly the way you want with CSS. To do that you would need information like paper-size. `page-break-inside` is the best you can do, but its not a guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [`page-break-inside` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html#propdef-page-break-inside):

```
div {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't do it.

Comment: `page-break-inside` is not widely supported yet (see http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/page-break-inside).

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get something hacked together with javascript.  You could measure the `offsetHeight` and `offsetTop` of each div, and compare that with the expected height in pixels of each page.  You'd have to experiment with different page heights to get it exact but something like this might work:

```
function paginateDivs() {

    var pageHeight = 800; // Experiment with different values here, this
                          // is 800 pixels.
    var lastPage = 0;

    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        var divBottom = divs[i].offsetTop + divs[i].offsetHeight;
        if (divBottom - lastPage > pageHeight) {
            lastPage = divs[i].offsetTop;
            divs[i].style.pageBreakBefore = "always";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cool and usefull solution but i can't use javascript for this.